# Printing a character from a 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

Using pointers, I am able to get to the actual character('i' in ElGenerico) that I want to print. But some weird character is getting printed on the screen, rather than my desired character.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *name[]={"Sami","Kevin","ElGenerico"};
    printf("%c",(*(name+2)+7));
    return 0;
}
```

With my use of `%s` output specifier, the output of this code is "ico".
But I want to print only the character 'i'. So I tried using `%c`, instead of `%s`. It doesn't work. Instead, a double headed arrow is printed.
Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `printf("%c",*(*(name+2)+7))`  (you are missing the leading `'*'`) Better to use `name[2][7]`

Comment: Thank You Sir, i understood now

Comment: Sir, why would you say that name[2][7] is the better choice?

Comment: It is more readable than pointer notation. `*(*(name + 2) + 7)` is a lot messier than `name[2][7]`, though both are entirely equivalent.

Comment: Just because the language allows us to use something doesn't mean that we should. `name[2][7]` = readable. `*(*(name + 2) + 7)` = unreadable. `7[2[name]]` = unreadable. `name??(2??)??(7??)` = unreadable. `7<:2<:name:>:>` = unreadable. There's endless ways that you can write extremely ugly but valid C. That doesn't mean that we should use those ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using bracket notation for improved readability.

Initially, you had this:

```
printf("%c",(*(name+2)+7));
```

You would still need to dereference with * to get the desired output.
That would give you this:

```
printf("%c",*(*(name+2)+7));
```

However, that's still a bit confusing and not very readable. You could make it much cleaner by using bracket notation, like this:

```
printf("%c", name[2][7]);
```

Now there's much less room for error and you still get the expected output.

Your final code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char* name[] = {"Sami", "Kevin", "ElGenerico"};
  printf("%c", name[2][7]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to the wrong address. Use this instead:

```
printf("%c",(*(name[2]+7)));
```

Since you are referring to the third element in the `name` array, you can use

```
name[2]
```

Then you wanted to put the 7th element of the word `ElGenerico`, hence we need to add 7 to the address:

```
name[2] + 7
```

After we get the correct address, then we print out the value of that address, and we use the `*` sign:

```
*(name[2] + 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%c",*(*(name+2)+7));
```

I used this, and it's solved, thanks for the help @David and @rcs...

Comment: This is why we don't write such trashy code but instead `name[2][7]`, which is 100% equivalent.